# Mongrel & Apache - 403 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mongrel

I'm trying to get my rails application up and running with Rails and Mongrel. I keep getting a 403 permission denied Apache error when pointing my browser to the application.

I can confirm that my mongrel_rails instances are running (ports 3001, 3002 and 3003).

Here is my vhost.conf:

```
<Proxy balancer://mongrelcluster>
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3003
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.domain.co.uk
  ServerAlias subdomain.domain.co.uk
  ProxyPass / balancer://mongrelcluster/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mongrelcluster/
  ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

I figure I must be missing something here. I've tried adding a DocumentRoot directive within to my virtual host which points to the root of my application, but to no avail.

Here is some output from my mongrel log (RE port 3003):

> ** Signals ready.  TERM => stop.  USR2 => restart.  INT => stop (no restart).
>   ** Rails signals registered.  HUP => reload (without restart).  It might not work well.
>   ** Mongrel 1.2.0.pre2 available at 0.0.0.0:3003 2012-08-08 10:32:14 +0000: Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in
>   `block in process' <internal:prelude>:10:in`synchronize'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in
>   `process'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:165:in`
>   block in process_client'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in
>   `each'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:164:in`
>   process_client'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/lib/mongrel.rb:291:in
>   `block (2 levels) in run'

I can see there is an error with dispatch somewhere (this error is only prevalent on the third and final port).
I have run

```
gem install dispatch
```

yet I'm still getting this issue. I'm unaware if the problem is with apache, mongrel, or both.

Any tips?